# Opening Sublime Text 2 from Terminal Problems

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, ibus, sublime-text

When I run the command `sudo sublime` from my terminal, it opens the program but will not allow me to run any other commands in my terminal until I close sublime text. This doesn't work because I'm trying to run tests from the terminal while making changes to my project on sublime text.

Right after Sublime Text opens from the terminal, I get this error:

```
(sublime:3522): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/mitch/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
```

I have tried figuring out what that warning means but have gotten no where. I'm very new to Ubuntu and appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:**

- Open a new terminal tab or a new terminal.

**Option 2:**

- Try:

  ```
  gksu sublime &
  ```

  The `&` tell the terminal not to wait for the program to finish.

Comment: The second method didn't work unfortunately :( I could open a tab, but i'm more wanting to find out why its giving me the IBUS warning and how to fix the problem instead of working around it.

Comment: Try running with gksudo (or gksu) not sudo this should set up the environment variables properly.

Comment: Awesome, I had to install gksu and now when I run `gksu sublime &` it stops the hanging. Thank you!

Comment: Great. I have edited the original so it is clear to others!